# Create Table Script in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server

When I Generate a script for Particular table  in SQL Server Extra line is added in my Script

What is the purpose of that line in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Thanks.

```
PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
```

Comment: You can find out everything you need to know about the options for `CREATE TABLE` in BOL [Create Table SQL 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hereunder explain each line which you have asked in short

PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
When ON, the percentage of free space specified by FILLFACTOR is applied to the intermediate level pages of the index. When OFF or a FILLFACTOR value it not specified, the intermediate level pages are filled to near capacity leaving enough space for at least one row of the maximum size the index can have, considering the set of keys on the intermediate pages. The default is OFF.

STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
When ON, out-of-date index statistics are not automatically recomputed. When OFF, automatic statistics updating are enabled. The default is OFF.

IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    Specifies the error response when an insert operation attempts to insert duplicate key values into a unique index. The IGNORE_DUP_KEY option applies only to insert operations after the index is created or rebuilt. The option has no effect when executing CREATE INDEX, ALTER INDEX, or UPDATE. The default is OFF.

```
ON

    A warning message will occur when duplicate key values are inserted into a unique index. Only the rows violating the uniqueness constraint will fail. 
OFF

    An error message will occur when duplicate key values are inserted into a unique index. The entire INSERT operation will be rolled back. 

IGNORE_DUP_KEY cannot be set to ON for indexes created on a view, non-unique indexes, XML indexes, spatial indexes, and filtered indexes.

To view IGNORE_DUP_KEY, use sys.indexes.

In backward compatible syntax, WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY is equivalent to WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON.
```

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
When ON, row locks are allowed when you access the index. The Database Engine determines when row locks are used. When OFF, row locks are not used. The default is ON.

ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
When ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCK = ON, row-, page-, and table-level locks are allowed when you access the index. The Database Engine chooses the appropriate lock and can escalate the lock from a row or page lock to a table lock. For more information, see Lock Escalation (Database Engine). When ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCK = OFF, only a table-level lock is allowed when you access the index. For more information about configuring the locking granularity for an index, see Customizing Locking for an Index.

Answer (score 0):

When set to `ON`, then it is used in conjunction with `FILLFACTOR`.

In brief, when creating/rebuilding a table/index you can specify a fill factor. This is effectively a percentage which indicates how full each page of the data file should be. If you specify 80 for example you leave the remaining 20 free so that when new records are inserted they can be added to the appropriate page, without having to move other data off of that page and onto another to make space.

The result of having `PAD_INDEX = ON` and setting a `FILLFACTOR` is that the table will be larger than it needs to be, but you will see better performance when doing inserts. This wont be noticeable on small tables but is relevant as tables grow.

Comment: Any Example is there?